# ./byfn.sh: line 116: docker-compose: command not found (Hyperledger .byfn.sh -m up Error)

Tags: docker-compose, hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger

I am trying to install Hyperledger sample on Ubuntu 14.04.

Followed all the steps in the tutorial. I am stuck at Build your first network script. When I run ./bynf.sh -m -up I get the following error:

```
boss@ubuntu:/tmp/fabric-samples/first-network$ ./byfn.sh -m up
Starting with channel 'mychannel' and CLI timeout of '10000'
Continue (y/n)? y
proceeding ...
./byfn.sh: line 116: docker-compose: command not found
ERROR !!!! Unable to start network
Error response from daemon: No such container: cli
boss@ubuntu:/tmp/fabric-samples/first-network$
```

Answer (score 0):

Did not have Docker Compose Installed on my Ubuntu.
Followed the steps in the link below and got it working:

https://docs.docker.com/compose/install/#install-compose